# returning reference from method

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

```
class A : boost::noncopyable{
}; 
class B{
    A & conn() const;
};
```

How would i declare and implement conn() given that:

- conn should create and return a reference to an object of type A.
- i can't break B's interface in client code using B.
- i want to prevent my code to leak      memory, so i cannot simply return
  references to objects in heap.

I didn't find any implementation of smart pointers that wouldn't break client code since there's no conversion to type A*, and i left client code untouched then i'd have memory leaks.

Sincerely,

Comment: Why are you returning a reference?  Also, I'm not sure what you mean about smart pointers; where do you need to convert to `A*`?

Comment: Must conn() create a new instance each time it is called?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: i can't return a copy since the boost::noncopyable prevents me from return a copy, also i cannot return a pointer since that's not the semantics the client code expects.

Comment: OK, I think my answer gives you something that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: I have added a small example. I really think it would be better if the conn() constmethod were to return a const A& though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could satisfy your three requirements by having `conn()` create a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr` would suit this case) to a new A, place it in a data member container of such smart pointers, and return a reference to the object managed by the smart pointer. You would have to declare the container `mutable` though, since your `conn()` method is `const`. I am not saying it is a good design though, just a was to meet your requirements. For example, using c++11:

```
class B {

 public:
  inline A& conn() const {
    data_.emplace_back(new A);
    return *(data_.back().get());
  }

 private:
  mutable std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> data_;
};
```

The lifetime of all the A objects is bound to B. BTW bear in mind that your interface provides non-const references to A objects, via a const method. This is not very good!

Comment: +1.  This is the idea I had in my head, but was too lazy to turn into an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Return a reference to a function-level static object:

```
A& b::conn( ) const
{
    static A theA;
    return theA;
}
```

I'm not advocating that this is a good thing to do but it's one way of solving the problem.

Comment: ok, but this doesn't meet the 'create and return' requirement, in your code that happens once.

Comment: Well, in that case you could have a static vector of pointers to A's - again I'm not saying that this is the right solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `A` instance as a data member of `B` to be able to return a reference (or use a static instance inside `conn`, but that brings a ton of trouble and should be avoided like fire). This doesn't break the API, but it will break the ABI.