# Control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++, qt, return

The following code snippet generates some warning messages when compiling:

```
Cluster& Myclass::getCluster(const Point &p)
{
    foreach (Cluster c, *this)
        foreach (Point point, c)
            if (point == p)
                return c;
}
```

The warnings are:

1. reference to local variable 'c' returned [enabled by default]
2. control reaches end of non-void function [when using `-Wreturn-type`]

I know that I am not returning a value if the condition fails. However, when I try `return 0` it gave me error.

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: What do you mean "when I try return 0 it gave me error"? Where did you include `return 0` and what was the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your function can legitimately fail to find a matching `Cluster`, then you should have it return a pointer:

```
Cluster* Myclass::getCluster(const Point &p)
{
    foreach (Cluster c, *this)
        foreach (Point point, c)
            if (point == p)
                return &c;
    return 0; // or return nullptr; in C++11
}
```

But this doesn't work yet, because `c` is a local variable. So you make it a reference, like this:

```
Cluster* Myclass::getCluster(const Point &p)
{
    foreach (Cluster& c, *this)
        foreach (Point point, c)
            if (point == p)
                return &c;
    return 0; // or "return nullptr;" in C++11
}
```

Comment: iterating by reference in the inner loop aswell would most likely be preferable: `foreach (const Point& point, c)`.
`

Comment: @TonyK Could you give a theory link about Returning a local varaible as a reference?

Comment: @Dewsworld: I'm not returning a local variable as a reference -- I'm returning the address of `c` (which, because `c` is a reference, is the address of an already existing `Cluster`). The `&` in line 6 is the "address-of" operator, and the `&` in line 3 declares `c` as a reference. This source of confusion is built into `C++`.

Comment: @TonyK I should have understood this on my first look! Didn't point that c is getting address from ***this** which is not local. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The first means that `c` is a local variable. As such, it will go out of scope and die when the function returns. Since you are returning by reference, the caller gets a dangling reference. The other error is that you fail to return anything under certain conditions. Returning 0 doesn't help, because the return type is a **reference to Cluster**. You need some mechanism to ensure that you return a Cluster reference to a Cluster that doesn't die immediately. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684296/returning-reference-from-method/9684917#9684917).

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c` *is* a local variable, as it's declared and defined inside the `getCluster` function. By returning a reference to it, when the function returns that reference "point" to where the variable *used* to be.

For the other warning, what if the condition is never true, then what does the function return?

Comment: You might add that his `foreach` is a lie, since he won't actually execute for each value.  Such lies tend to cause confusion for someone reading the code.

Comment: @James: Anybody who gets confused by a simple loop like this shouldn't be reading code in the first place.

Comment: @TonyK Anybody who writes intentionally misleading code shouldn't be writing code in the first place.  Saying you're going to do the following for each element in a sequence, and then not doing it, is intentionally misleading.

Comment: @James: It's using a standard programming construct to perform a task, that's all. "Intentionally misleading" is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

> reference to local variable 'c' returned [enabled by default]

You should not return a reference to a local variable because once the function is returned the variable does not exist anymore and hence you have reference to something that does not exist. The compiler warns you of this.

> control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Once you specify a return type for a function, every control path should return the value. If the condition evaluates to `false` then your code never returns anything hence the compiler complains.

Comment: @shobi: You should be returning a pointer which points to dynamically allocated memory in case of success, In case of failure you return a `NULL`, And importantly you should doccument the behavior of this api that in case of success the user should deallocate the allocated memory.

Comment: @Als: No, you shouldn't be allocating memory here. The `Cluster` already exists -- all you have to do is return its address.

Comment: @TonyK: if the `Cluster` was being created locally, I don't see how returning its address will solve OPs problem.

Comment: @Als: No `Cluster` is created locally if you use a reference -- see my answer.